# Build Error: go build -o /<PATH>/.vscode/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l . when debugging application Mac OS/M1 VScode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my Golang console application in VScode.

I've following `launch.json` file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "${fileDirname}"
    }
]}
```

When I try to run debugger, I'm getting following error:

```
Starting: /Users/chandan/go/bin/dlv dap --listen=127.0.0.1:50512 --log-dest=3 from /Users/chandan/Workspace/2023/Go/hammer-bitcoin/.vscode

DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:50512

Build Error: go build -o /Users/chandan/Workspace/2023/Go/hammer-bitcoin/.vscode/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .

no Go files in /Users/chandan/Workspace/2023/Go/hammer-bitcoin/.vscode (exit status 1)
```

My DLV version:

```
chandan@~/Workspace/2023/Go (main) ± ➜ dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.20.1
Build: $Id: 96e65b6c615845d42e0e31d903f6475b0e4ece6e $
```

Visual Studio Code:

```
Version: 1.76.1 (Universal)
```

MacOS Apple M1

I'm not sure what's wrong, can anyone help debugging setting up the debugger.

### EDIT

When I update the configuration to :

```
 "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Package",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "auto",
        "program": "/Users/chandan/Workspace/2023/Go/hammer-bitcoin/"
    }
]
```

The debugging seems to execute, however, I'm seeing another error:

```
Unable to process `evaluate`: debuggee is running
```

Comment: what does `fileDirname` resolve to?

Comment: I think it's /Users/chandan/Workspace/2023/Go/hammer-bitcoin/.vscode "Path to the program folder (or any go file within that folder) when in `debug` or `test` mode, and to the pre-built binary file to debug in `exec` mode. If it is not an absolute path, the extension interpretes it as a workspace relative path."